# Structure not functioning on create user tab in Sandbox OIM

Tags: oracle, user-interface, sandbox, identity, oim

In Oracle Identity Manager I have a problem where when I activate a sandbox and I want to change something on the create user tab on the User Interface I click on a field and nothing happens. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I tried rolling back old sandboxes and putting extra logs but there is nothing that can help me.
In all other tabs it works fine. For example in modify user it works. Only in this tab it doesn't work.
I use Firefox browser. I tried through Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome and it works fine there.

Comment: Do you mean its a browser specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

FF works fine for me.  Some things to further troubleshoot your issue.
What are the specific steps you are taking to replicate the issue?]
Have you tried different versions of FF?

Steps that i took.(PS3)
1. Activate sandbox
2. Click manage
3. Click Users
4. Click create
5. Click Customize
6. Click structure(errored out as there are required fields, put random values in lname, org and user type)
7. Clicked structure again, this time it worked and i have normal control over the fields i would like to customize.

Comment: I tried 3 different versions. About 30 minutes ago it worked (I don't know why) and now it stopped working again.